# How to Solve Error While Installing Language Check?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'am installing language-check library using this command. The purpose is I want to use language-check for the pycontractions library that require language-check library.

My python version is 3.8.13

```
pip install language-check
```

I got following error:

````
 Running setup.py clean for language-check
Failed to build language-check
Installing collected packages: language-check
    Running setup.py install for language-check ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\NLP\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vvhnccvk\\language-check_21a0d3b22c9540f4908d4e0f9da750b7\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vvhnccvk\\language-check_21a0d3b22c9540f4908d4e0f9da750b7\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-y0oeqs59\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\NLP\Include\language-check'
         cwd: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vvhnccvk\language-check_21a0d3b22c9540f4908d4e0f9da750b7\
    Complete output (35 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vvhnccvk\language-check_21a0d3b22c9540f4908d4e0f9da750b7\setup.py", line 595, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vvhnccvk\language-check_21a0d3b22c9540f4908d4e0f9da750b7\setup.py", line 590, in main
        run_setup_hooks(config)
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vvhnccvk\language-check_21a0d3b22c9540f4908d4e0f9da750b7\setup.py", line 561, in run_setup_hooks
        language_tool_hook(config)
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vvhnccvk\language-check_21a0d3b22c9540f4908d4e0f9da750b7\setup.py", line 584, in language_tool_hook
        download_lt()
      File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vvhnccvk\language-check_21a0d3b22c9540f4908d4e0f9da750b7\download_lt.py", line 128, in download_lt
        with closing(urlopen(url)) as u:
      File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\NLP\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
        return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
      File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\NLP\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\NLP\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
        response = self.parent.error(
      File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\NLP\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
        result = self._call_chain(*args)
      File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\NLP\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\NLP\lib\urllib\request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
        return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
      File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\NLP\lib\urllib\request.py", line 531, in open
        response = meth(req, response)
      File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\NLP\lib\urllib\request.py", line 640, in http_response
        response = self.parent.error(
      File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\NLP\lib\urllib\request.py", line 569, in error
        return self._call_chain(*args)
      File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\NLP\lib\urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\NLP\lib\urllib\request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
        raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\NLP\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vvhnccvk\\language-check_21a0d3b22c9540f4908d4e0f9da750b7\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vvhnccvk\\language-check_21a0d3b22c9540f4908d4e0f9da750b7\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-y0oeqs59\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --instal
```

Any suggestions to solve it ?
````